# Beat Ornstein and Smough in NG+

Tags: dark-souls

I would like some advice on how I can beat Ornstein and Smough in NG+. I didn't intend to finish NG+ so I didn't prepare myself before killing Gwyn (Just pyromancy flame +5 with Fireball e.g.).
I have Great Scythe +14, Uchigatana +15, Claymore Fire +9. I did not receive the large ember yet.
I tried killing smough first and I tried with and without Solaire (kind of useless, just speeds up the first half of the fight).
Any tips? Should I leave Anor Londo and make Queelags Furysword? Should I level my Pyromancy Flame and get some better Pyromancys (I did not go to Queelana after the Chaos of Bed to receive the gift)?
Vit 45, Dex 45, Str 16, End 35
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I personally find it easier to kill Ornstein first, because he has less health, so the transition comes faster, and the enhanced Smough is slower. You won't get Leo's ring this way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patience is going to be your best shot. I've almost exclusively used the Great Scythe for all my fights against O&S so I've got quite a bit of experience there. It's tricky because you can't do locked attacks on Smough otherwise your scythe will just hit his hammer and you can only do one attack at a time otherwise you run out of stamina for dodging. I recommend using Solaire as he is great for pulling one if not both of them long enough for you to get some dps down. I prefer killing Smough first because I feel that Ornstein's second fight phase is much easier than his first. He does gain some of Smough's AOE but he still has much narrower hitboxes and you can easily fight right underneath his spear. The only time you need to get out is when he does his electric belly flop, then use the Scythe's 2h r2 attack as a gapcloser to get back in fighting range.

In regards to your comment about Quelaag's Furysword, I would recommend against using it for O&S for the sole reason that its hitboxes are really funky. I've tried using it and Smough wound up passively blocking most of my swings with his hammer. Couple this with its low-ish base damage and lower scaling than the scythe and you're in for a long fight. I would stick with your Uchigatana and Great Scythe for this fight depending on which you are more comfortable with. The nice thing about those two is that you can also enchant them for extra damage (darkmoon blade/sunlight blade if you have faith, crystal magic weapon if you have int, and charcoal pine resin/gold pine resin if you don't have either of the previous options). I've always gone for glass cannon builds, using `crystal magic weapon` and `power within` to significantly boost my dps in fights but it all boils down to how patiently can you fight. Pay attention, learn their attack queues, and don't burn up all your stamina.

Comment: Thank you! Patience was indeed key, I went solo and defeated Ornstein first, after that it was waiting really long for an opening, landing a quick hit and again waiting. Toughest fight so far.

Comment: Good luck with manus if you have the DLC ;)

Comment: I do have the DLC. Missed a lot of it on my original playthrough so I plan on finishing it on NG+. I also missed the painted world. Wonder what else I missed.